# How to calculate the probability of shared categories without replacement?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, independence

Given the following distribution of books on a bookshelf:

|  | Hardcover | Paperback | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fiction | 13 | 59 | **72** |
| Nonfiction | 15 | 8 | **23** |
| **Total** | **28** | **67** | **95** |

Choosing a fiction book first and then a hardcover book second...

*With* replacement the probability is $\frac{72}{95}\times\frac{28}{95}=0.2234$

How does one calculate the probability *without* replacement?

Note: This is question is based on Exercise 3.26 (page 114) from Diez, D., Çetinkaya-Rundel, M., & Barr, C. (2019). *OpenIntro Statistics: Fourth Edition*. OpenIntro, Inc.

Comment: Confusion reigns: You're picking **one** book, so how can can sampling with or without replacement be relevant? // Do you want $P(FH)  = 13/95$ based on an observed cell count? // Are you conflating the expected count in cell $FH$ under the null hypothesis of independence (under test) with observed count in that cell?

Comment: Clarification: We are selecting **two** books. First, a fiction book, then second, a hardcover book.

Comment: Write out the two cases: the first book is hardcover, and the first book is not hardcover. Each will have a different probability that the second book is hardcover, given that first book. Your final result will look like $a \times b + c \times d$.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy or anyone else...I came across the wiki about the `self-study` tag, so I removed the calculated answer. (This is my first Stack Exchange post.) Should I remove my "Answer" post in its entirety and leave it with just the comments? Or how does one properly wrap up this "Question" post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Arya McCarthy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/155836/arya-mccarthy) for the tip to use $a \times b + c \times d$, where

- $a$ is the probability of choosing a paperback fiction = $\frac{59}{95}$
- $c$ is the probability of choosing a hardcover fiction = $\frac{13}{95}$
- given the first book is paperback, $b$ is then the probability of choosing a hardcover without replacement = $\frac{28}{94}$
- given the first book is hardcover, $d$ is then the probability of choosing a hardcover *from the 27 remaining* without replacement = $\frac{27}{94}$